# Can Xcode Debug breakpoints change how program is run?

Tags: debugging, xcode8

I'm trying to find out why when saving the state of a boolean property, there are times when it does not seem to save when I run the program, then stop, and re-run, to simulate turning my phone off.

When I put breakpoints at each saveState() (method to save userDefaults) and run through a series of tests, turning the property on/off (switching from T to F), it works every time correctly.

However, when I turn the breakpoints off, and run through the exact same series of events (turning property on/off), I don't get the same results all the time.

Is there a reason that running through Debug would perform with different outcome than a normal run?

Comment: You've found a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug !

Comment: punated: timing issue? Debug mode executes slower than in Release. Maybe in Debug there's enough time to actually save (to the underlying storage) and in Release the phone is turned off before it is done?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure.  This happens in the simulator too -- would that make a difference?  With that said, I don't know why this seems to have fixed the issue, but I moved the line of code to assign that particular property to a userDefault value from the end of the saveState and loadState functions to the top (first value saved).  What ever works I guess, but I wish I knew why?